# Latex file cannot be compiled by latexmk

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, citing, compiling, compilation-error

I am trying to submit my latex project to [JMLR](https://www.jmlr.org/format/authors-guide.html) which compiles fine locally and on [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com). However, it cannot be compiled on JMLR's latexmk. Does anyone know why it can't be compiled with 3 runs of the compiler and how I can fix that..? :( I'm at my wits end since there is no technical support from a volunteer-run journal. The error messages are displayed below, thanks. The errors seem to be coming from references and citations being not resolved but they are not an issue locally on my computer or on overleaf. What is going on..? I added a snippet of the bib file after the error messages below.

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
Latexmk: Removing all generated files
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "paper.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation `Arp23' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Aub18' on page 6 undefined on input line 269
  Citation `Bal15' on page 3 undefined on input line 178
  Citation `Bal16' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Bal16' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Bal17' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Bar19' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Bar22' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Bay11' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Can15' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Citation `Can15' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Cha13' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Cha21' on page 6 undefined on input line 267
  Citation `Che14' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Che20' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Com16' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Des14' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Dev20' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Don09' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Don13' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Fan18' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Fan22' on page 6 undefined on input line 254
  Citation `Far10' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Fen21' on page 10 undefined on input line 387
  Citation `Fen21' on page 10 undefined on input line 399
  Citation `Fen21' on page 11 undefined on input line 443
  Citation `Fen21' on page 7 undefined on input line 288
  Citation `Fle18' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Fog16' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Citation `Fog16' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Gho20' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Gho22' on page 3 undefined on input line 178
  Citation `Gho22' on page 3 undefined on input line 193
  Citation `Gho22' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Gre02' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Gro17' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Gru07' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Gun13' on page 3 undefined on input line 178
  Citation `Han13' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Ho22' on page 6 undefined on input line 267
  Citation `Hsu47' on page 7 undefined on input line 288
  Citation `Hua12' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Hua13' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Jac91' on page 4 undefined on input line 206
  Citation `Jav13' on page 6 undefined on input line 250
  Citation `Jor94' on page 4 undefined on input line 206
  Citation `Kab03' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Kab16' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Kha07' on page 4 undefined on input line 204
  Citation `Klu19' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Kon20' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Kri19' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Krz12' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Les17' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Li18' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Li19' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Li23' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Lim12' on page 6 undefined on input line 278
  Citation `Ma19' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Mag09' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Mai20' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Mak19' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Mak20' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Maz19' on page 6 undefined on input line 278
  Citation `Mcl04' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Mon21' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Mont21' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Net13' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Citation `Net13' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Pal21' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Pal22' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Pan20' on page 6 undefined on input line 269
  Citation `Pri90' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Ran11' on page 11 undefined on input line 443
  Citation `Ran11' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Sch14' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Sed16' on page 4 undefined on input line 204
  Citation `Sei11' on page 6 undefined on input line 278
  Citation `Sha17' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `She19' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Soh21' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Sta10' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Sur19' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Tan23' on page 5 undefined on input line 248
  Citation `Vie02' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Vil13' on page 6 undefined on input line 252
  Citation `Wan15' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Wan22' on page 6 undefined on input line 254
  Citation `Yi14' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Yi15' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Yuk12' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Zha20' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Zha22' on page 6 undefined on input line 267
  Citation `Zho16' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Zho21' on page 6 undefined on input line 254
  Citation `Zhu17' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Zil23' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Reference `LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 138
  Reference `appen:MLR_implementation' on page 12 undefined on input line 479
  Reference `eq:GAMP' on page 10 undefined on input line 392
  Reference `eq:GAMP' on page 12 undefined on input line 479
  Reference `eq:GAMP' on page 8 undefined on input line 315
  Reference `eq:GAMP' on page 8 undefined on input line 318
  Reference `eq:GAMP' on page 8 undefined on input line 322
  Reference `eq:GAMP' on page 9 undefined on input line 368
  Reference `eq:MAR_model_concise' on page 5 undefined on input line 241
  Reference `eq:MGLM_model' on page 4 undefined on input line 204
  Reference `eq:MLR_model' on page 11 undefined on input line 467
  Reference `eq:MLR_model' on page 11 undefined on input line 471
  Reference `eq:MLR_model' on page 2 undefined on input line 149
  Reference `eq:MLR_model' on page 2 undefined on input line 154
  Reference `eq:MLR_model' on page 3 undefined on input line 198
  Reference `eq:MOE_def' on page 11 undefined on input line 467
  Reference `eq:MOE_def' on page 4 undefined on input line 215
  Reference `eq:SE_Mk1B' on page 11 undefined on input line 441
  Reference `eq:SE_Mk1B' on page 9 undefined on input line 354
  Reference `eq:SE_Sigk1' on page 9 undefined on input line 354
  Reference `eq:SE_Tk1B' on page 11 undefined on input line 441
  Reference `eq:SE_TkTh' on page 11 undefined on input line 441
  Reference `eq:Sig0_def' on page 9 undefined on input line 354
  Reference `eq:Sig_comps' on page 11 undefined on input line 441
  Reference `eq:convex_reg' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Reference `eq:convex_reg' on page 6 undefined on input line 273
  Reference `eq:eff_cov_def' on page 11 undefined on input line 441
  Reference `eq:fk_opt_def' on page 12 undefined on input line 479
  Reference `eq:gk_opt_def' on page 12 undefined on input line 479
  Reference `eq:hk_def' on page 9 undefined on input line 385
  Reference `eq:matrix-GAMP_SE_result1' on page 10 undefined on input line 399
  Reference `eq:matrix-GAMP_SE_result2' on page 10 undefined on input line 399
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 1 undefined on input line 135
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 10 undefined on input line 392
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 2 undefined on input line 149
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 3 undefined on input line 181
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 3 undefined on input line 186
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 4 undefined on input line 215
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 4 undefined on input line 231
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 5 undefined on input line 239
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 7 undefined on input line 292
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 8 undefined on input line 299
  Reference `eq:matrix-GLM' on page 8 undefined on input line 322
  Reference `eq:max-affine_model' on page 11 undefined on input line 467
  Reference `eq:max-affine_model' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Reference `eq:max-affine_model' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Reference `eq:max-affine_model' on page 3 undefined on input line 181
  Reference `eq:max-affine_model' on page 5 undefined on input line 241
  Reference `eq:max-affine_model' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Reference `eq:max_affine_LS' on page 3 undefined on input line 193
  Reference `eq:norm_sq_corr' on page 12 undefined on input line 481
  Reference `fig:diff_corr' on page 12 undefined on input line 484
  Reference `fig:diff_noise' on page 12 undefined on input line 484
  Reference `fig:diff_prop' on page 12 undefined on input line 484
  Reference `prop:optimal_fk' on page 5 undefined on input line 239
  Reference `sec:max-affine_reg' on page 5 undefined on input line 242
  Reference `sec:sims' on page 5 undefined on input line 241
  Reference `subsec:prelim_model' on page 10 undefined on input line 392
  Reference `subsec:prelim_model' on page 9 undefined on input line 383
  Reference `subsec:proof_GAMP' on page 10 undefined on input line 399
  Reference `subsec:prop_proof' on page 11 undefined on input line 463
  Reference `thm:GAMP' on page 10 undefined on input line 401
  Reference `thm:GAMP' on page 10 undefined on input line 404
  Reference `thm:GAMP' on page 5 undefined on input line 239
  Reference `thm:GAMP' on page 6 undefined on input line 250
  Reference `thm:GAMP' on page 8 undefined on input line 319
  Reference `thm:GAMP' on page 8 undefined on input line 320
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'paper.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "paper.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation `Arp23' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Aub18' on page 6 undefined on input line 269
  Citation `Bal15' on page 3 undefined on input line 178
  Citation `Bal16' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Bal16' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Bal17' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Bar19' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Bar22' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Bay11' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Can15' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Citation `Can15' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Cha13' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Cha21' on page 6 undefined on input line 267
  Citation `Che14' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Che20' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Com16' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Des14' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Dev20' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Don09' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Don13' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Fan18' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Fan22' on page 6 undefined on input line 254
  Citation `Far10' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Fen21' on page 10 undefined on input line 387
  Citation `Fen21' on page 10 undefined on input line 399
  Citation `Fen21' on page 11 undefined on input line 443
  Citation `Fen21' on page 7 undefined on input line 288
  Citation `Fle18' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Fog16' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Citation `Fog16' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Gho20' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Gho22' on page 3 undefined on input line 178
  Citation `Gho22' on page 3 undefined on input line 193
  Citation `Gho22' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Gre02' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Gro17' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Gru07' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Gun13' on page 3 undefined on input line 178
  Citation `Han13' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Ho22' on page 6 undefined on input line 267
  Citation `Hsu47' on page 7 undefined on input line 288
  Citation `Hua12' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Hua13' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Jac91' on page 4 undefined on input line 206
  Citation `Jav13' on page 6 undefined on input line 250
  Citation `Jor94' on page 4 undefined on input line 206
  Citation `Kab03' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Kab16' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Kha07' on page 4 undefined on input line 204
  Citation `Klu19' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Kon20' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Kri19' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Krz12' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Les17' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Li18' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Li19' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Li23' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Lim12' on page 6 undefined on input line 278
  Citation `Ma19' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Mag09' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Mai20' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Mak19' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Mak20' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Maz19' on page 6 undefined on input line 278
  Citation `Mcl04' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Mon21' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Mont21' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Net13' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Citation `Net13' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Pal21' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Pal22' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Pan20' on page 6 undefined on input line 269
  Citation `Pri90' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Ran11' on page 11 undefined on input line 443
  Citation `Ran11' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Sch14' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Sed16' on page 4 undefined on input line 204
  Citation `Sei11' on page 6 undefined on input line 278
  Citation `Sha17' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `She19' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Soh21' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Sta10' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Sur19' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Tan23' on page 5 undefined on input line 248
  Citation `Vie02' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Vil13' on page 6 undefined on input line 252
  Citation `Wan15' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Wan22' on page 6 undefined on input line 254
  Citation `Yi14' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Yi15' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Yuk12' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Zha20' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Zha22' on page 6 undefined on input line 267
  Citation `Zho16' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Zho21' on page 6 undefined on input line 254
  Citation `Zhu17' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Zil23' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Reference `LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 138
  Reference `appen:MLR_implementation' on page 12 undefined on input line 479
  Reference `fig:diff_corr' on page 12 undefined on input line 484
  Reference `fig:diff_noise' on page 12 undefined on input line 484
  Reference `fig:diff_prop' on page 12 undefined on input line 484
  Reference `sec:max-affine_reg' on page 5 undefined on input line 242
  Reference `subsec:proof_GAMP' on page 10 undefined on input line 399
  Reference `subsec:prop_proof' on page 11 undefined on input line 463
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'paper.out'
------------
Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "paper.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation `Arp23' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Aub18' on page 6 undefined on input line 269
  Citation `Bal15' on page 3 undefined on input line 178
  Citation `Bal16' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Bal16' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Bal17' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Bar19' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Bar22' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Bay11' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Can15' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Citation `Can15' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Cha13' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Cha21' on page 6 undefined on input line 267
  Citation `Che14' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Che20' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Com16' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Des14' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Dev20' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Don09' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Don13' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Fan18' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Fan22' on page 6 undefined on input line 254
  Citation `Far10' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Fen21' on page 10 undefined on input line 387
  Citation `Fen21' on page 10 undefined on input line 399
  Citation `Fen21' on page 11 undefined on input line 443
  Citation `Fen21' on page 7 undefined on input line 288
  Citation `Fle18' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Fog16' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Citation `Fog16' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Gho20' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Gho22' on page 3 undefined on input line 178
  Citation `Gho22' on page 3 undefined on input line 193
  Citation `Gho22' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Gre02' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Gro17' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Gru07' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Gun13' on page 3 undefined on input line 178
  Citation `Han13' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Ho22' on page 6 undefined on input line 267
  Citation `Hsu47' on page 7 undefined on input line 288
  Citation `Hua12' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Hua13' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Jac91' on page 4 undefined on input line 206
  Citation `Jav13' on page 6 undefined on input line 250
  Citation `Jor94' on page 4 undefined on input line 206
  Citation `Kab03' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Kab16' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Kha07' on page 4 undefined on input line 204
  Citation `Klu19' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Kon20' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Kri19' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Krz12' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Les17' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Li18' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Li19' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Li23' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Lim12' on page 6 undefined on input line 278
  Citation `Ma19' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Mag09' on page 6 undefined on input line 281
  Citation `Mai20' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Mak19' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Mak20' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Maz19' on page 6 undefined on input line 278
  Citation `Mcl04' on page 2 undefined on input line 151
  Citation `Mon21' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Mont21' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Net13' on page 3 undefined on input line 174
  Citation `Net13' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Pal21' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Pal22' on page 6 undefined on input line 264
  Citation `Pan20' on page 6 undefined on input line 269
  Citation `Pri90' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Ran11' on page 11 undefined on input line 443
  Citation `Ran11' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Sch14' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Sed16' on page 4 undefined on input line 204
  Citation `Sei11' on page 6 undefined on input line 278
  Citation `Sha17' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `She19' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Soh21' on page 3 undefined on input line 179
  Citation `Sta10' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Sur19' on page 4 undefined on input line 233
  Citation `Tan23' on page 5 undefined on input line 248
  Citation `Vie02' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Vil13' on page 6 undefined on input line 252
  Citation `Wan15' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Wan22' on page 6 undefined on input line 254
  Citation `Yi14' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Yi15' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Yuk12' on page 4 undefined on input line 212
  Citation `Zha20' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Zha22' on page 6 undefined on input line 267
  Citation `Zho16' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Citation `Zho21' on page 6 undefined on input line 254
  Citation `Zhu17' on page 6 undefined on input line 262
  Citation `Zil23' on page 2 undefined on input line 161
  Reference `LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 138
  Reference `appen:MLR_implementation' on page 12 undefined on input line 479
  Reference `fig:diff_corr' on page 12 undefined on input line 484
  Reference `fig:diff_noise' on page 12 undefined on input line 484
  Reference `fig:diff_prop' on page 12 undefined on input line 484
  Reference `sec:max-affine_reg' on page 5 undefined on input line 242
  Reference `subsec:proof_GAMP' on page 10 undefined on input line 399
  Reference `subsec:prop_proof' on page 11 undefined on input line 463
Failure to make 'paper.pdf'
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of (pdf)latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 8 reference(s)
  Latex failed to resolve 197 citation(s)
```

This is a snippet (the front parts) of my bib file:

```
% Encoding: ISO-8859-1

%%% Books %%%

@book{Ash90,
  title={Information Theory},
  author={Ash, Robert B.},
  year={1990},
  publisher={Dover Publications Inc., New York}
}

@book{And09,
  title={An introduction to random matrices},
  author={Greg W. Anderson and Alice Guionnet and Ofer Zeitouni},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}

@inproceedings{Pal21,
    title={Support Recovery of Sparse Signals from a Mixture of Linear Measurements},
    author={Soumyabrata Pal and Arya Mazumdar and Venkata Gandikota},
    booktitle={Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems},
    year={2021},
}

@inproceedings{Kri19,
    title = {Sample {Complexity} of {Learning} {Mixture} of {Sparse} {Linear} {Regressions}},
    volume = {32},
    booktitle = {Advances in {Neural} {Information} {Processing} {Systems}},
    author = {Krishnamurthy, Akshay and Mazumdar, Arya and McGregor, Andrew and Pal, Soumyabrata},
    year = {2019},
}
```

Comment: are there errors from bibtex did you submit the bib file

Comment: Yes I did. I even submitted the .bbl file just to be safe. I tried submitting once with just the .bib file and another time with both the .bib file and the .bbl file. Both times give the same error for me. I can try to upload the bib file here if it is helpful for you,

**Edit:** I have added a snippet of my bib file to the question, at the very end after the error messages.

Comment: test your submission locally take the zip file and unpack it to a new empty directory and run latexmk there, does it work?

Comment: Yes it does (it also runs fine on overleaf). Also regarding the question you asked about errors from bibtex: What I shared above are all the errors that I saw. So I guess we can assume there no errors from bibtex. **I highly suspect the issue might be that it needs four runs of pdflatex to compile my tex file, but the production system of JMLR appears to do only three.**

Comment: remove bibtex replace \bibliography by pastng in the content of the bbl that should save a latex run

Comment: You mean in the main latex file I should replace "\bibliography" with the entire contents of the .bbl file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148029/discussion-between-resu-and-david-carlisle).