# Cannot compile Latex file on journal system

Tags: errors, citing, compiling, compilation-error, online

I'm trying to submit my tex file to [JMLR](https://www.jmlr.org/format/authors-guide.html). Everything's fine on my overleaf and latexmk on my computer, however when I submit it to the production system, it doesn't work on JMLR's latexmk, which results in failure in producing a PDF file.  After browsing around, I saw a similar question [SELatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694162/latex-file-cannot-be-compiled-by-latexmk), but unfortunately, they didn't hash it out. [JMLR](https://www.jmlr.org/format/authors-guide.html) is a volunteer-run team so they cannot afford technical help. :( Now I'm at my wits end...  Does anyone know what I can do? I've attached the output below:

```
    CALLING latexmk -norc -gg -pdf SOMETHING.tex DONE
```

From stderr, seems that latexmk doesn't recognize the references and citations, even though I submit both .bib and .bbl files;

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 March 2019, version: 4.63b.
Latexmk: Removing all generated files
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "paper.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'paper.bbl'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation `10.1145/1835804.1835817' on page 2 undefined on input line 423
  Citation `2008kernel' on page 3 undefined on input line 440
  Citation `BREGMAN1967200' on page 12 undefined on input line 728
  Citation `DUBOVITSKII19651' on page 20 undefined on input line 1037
  Citation `abbasi2011improved' on page 34 undefined on input line 1727
  Citation `abbasi2011improved' on page 34 undefined on input line 1735
  Citation `abbasi2011improved' on page 36 undefined on input line 1801
  Citation `abbeel2004apprenticeship' on page 7 undefined on input line 548
  Citation `agarwal2020flambe' on page 12 undefined on input line 736
  Citation `agarwal2020flambe' on page 3 undefined on input line 450
  Citation `agarwal2020flambe' on page 35 undefined on input line 1769
  Citation `agarwal2020flambe' on page 35 undefined on input line 1770
  Citation `agarwal2020flambe' on page 35 undefined on input line 1781
  Citation `agarwal2020flambe' on page 7 undefined on input line 568
  Citation `altman1999constrained' on page 33 undefined on input line 1565
  Citation `apprenticeship' on page 2 undefined on input line 425
  Citation `apprenticeship' on page 2 undefined on input line 427
  Citation `ayoub2020model' on page 12 undefined on input line 728
  Citation `ayoub2020model' on page 3 undefined on input line 441
  Citation `ayoub2020model' on page 3 undefined on input line 442
  Citation `beck2017first' on page 31 undefined on input line 1470
  Citation `beck2017first' on page 31 undefined on input line 1479
  Citation `beck2017first' on page 31 undefined on input line 1481
  Citation `beck2017first' on page 32 undefined on input line 1524
  Citation `boyd2004convex' on page 10 undefined on input line 654
  Citation `brantley2021constrained' on page 3 undefined on input line 449
  Citation `brantley2021constrained' on page 6 undefined on input line 510
  Citation `chen2016stochastic' on page 3 undefined on input line 448
  Citation `dani2008stochastic' on page 12 undefined on input line 728
  Citation `dann2017unifying' on page 34 undefined on input line 1725
  Citation `devroye2018total' on page 15 undefined on input line 853
  Citation `ding2021provably' on page 13 undefined on input line 765
  Citation `ding2021provably' on page 2 undefined on input line 425
  Citation `ding2021provably' on page 2 undefined on input line 427
  Citation `ding2021provably' on page 3 undefined on input line 449
  Citation `ding2021provably' on page 5 undefined on input line 494
  Citation `ding2021provably' on page 6 undefined on input line 510
  Citation `ding2021provably' on page 6 undefined on input line 546
  Citation `ding2021provably' on page 9 undefined on input line 611
  Citation `efroni2020exploration' on page 10 undefined on input line 657
  Citation `efroni2020exploration' on page 2 undefined on input line 425
  Citation `efroni2020exploration' on page 2 undefined on input line 427
  Citation `efroni2020exploration' on page 2 undefined on input line 430
  Citation `efroni2020exploration' on page 2 undefined on input line 431
  Citation `efroni2020exploration' on page 3 undefined on input line 449
  Citation `efroni2020exploration' on page 5 undefined on input line 485
  Citation `efroni2020exploration' on page 6 undefined on input line 546
  Citation `efroni2020exploration' on page 9 undefined on input line 611
  Citation `freedman_bernstein' on page 37 undefined on input line 1839
  Citation `garcia2015comprehensive' on page 2 undefined on input line 423
  Citation `hijazi2016constraint' on page 9 undefined on input line 618
  Citation `jin2020provably' on page 3 undefined on input line 442
  Citation `jin2020provably' on page 5 undefined on input line 485
  Citation `jin2020provably' on page 5 undefined on input line 494
  Citation `jin2021bellman' on page 12 undefined on input line 728
  Citation `jin2021bellman' on page 3 undefined on input line 442
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 12 undefined on input line 728
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 18 undefined on input line 984
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 21 undefined on input line 1063
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 3 undefined on input line 441
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 3 undefined on input line 442
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 3 undefined on input line 450
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 5 undefined on input line 485
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 5 undefined on input line 494
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 7 undefined on input line 561
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 7 undefined on input line 565
  Citation `kakade2020information' on page 7 undefined on input line 578
  Citation `mania2020active' on page 3 undefined on input line 450
  Citation `mania2020active' on page 7 undefined on input line 565
  Citation `miryoosefi2019reinforcement' on page 7 undefined on input line 548
  Citation `modi2022modelfree' on page 5 undefined on input line 494
  Citation `modi2022modelfree' on page 7 undefined on input line 568
  Citation `mordatch2012contact' on page 12 undefined on input line 734
  Citation `muandet2016kernel' on page 3 undefined on input line 440
  Citation `muandet2017kernel' on page 5 undefined on input line 485
  Citation `qiu2020upper' on page 3 undefined on input line 449
  Citation `rockafellar1970convex' on page 9 undefined on input line 618
  Citation `rockafellar1970convex' on page 9 undefined on input line 642
  Citation `rockafellar1970convex' on page 9 undefined on input line 646
  Citation `song2021pcmlp' on page 7 undefined on input line 565
  Citation `syed2008apprenticeship' on page 7 undefined on input line 548
  Citation `tewari2007optimistic' on page 3 undefined on input line 448
  Citation `todorov2005generalized' on page 12 undefined on input line 734
  Citation `uehara2021pessimistic' on page 12 undefined on input line 728
  Citation `uehara2021pessimistic' on page 15 undefined on input line 855
  Citation `uehara2021pessimistic' on page 7 undefined on input line 568
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 12 undefined on input line 736
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 17 undefined on input line 929
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 18 undefined on input line 984
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 3 undefined on input line 450
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 35 undefined on input line 1787
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 36 undefined on input line 1788
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 5 undefined on input line 485
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 5 undefined on input line 494
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 7 undefined on input line 577
  Citation `uehara2022representation' on page 7 undefined on input line 578
  Citation `vaswani2022nearoptimal' on page 3 undefined on input line 449
  Citation `wagener2019online' on page 12 undefined on input line 734
  Citation `wang2017primal' on page 3 undefined on input line 448
  Citation `wang2020randomized' on page 3 undefined on input line 448
  Citation `williams2015model' on page 12 undefined on input line 734
  Citation `wu2021offline' on page 10 undefined on input line 657
  Citation `wu2021offline' on page 2 undefined on input line 425
  Citation `wu2021offline' on page 3 undefined on input line 449
  Citation `wu2021offline' on page 5 undefined on input line 494
  Citation `wu2021offline' on page 6 undefined on input line 510
  Citation `wu2021offline' on page 6 undefined on input line 530
  Citation `wu2021offline' on page 6 undefined on input line 546
  Citation `yang2019sample' on page 7 undefined on input line 578
  Citation `yang2020provably' on page 3 undefined on input line 442
  Citation `yang2020provably' on page 5 undefined on input line 485
  Citation `yang2020provably' on page 5 undefined on input line 494
  Citation `yang2020reinforcement' on page 7 undefined on input line 578
  Citation `yu2021provably' on page 13 undefined on input line 765
  Citation `yu2021provably' on page 18 undefined on input line 984
  Citation `yu2021provably' on page 2 undefined on input line 425
  Citation `yu2021provably' on page 3 undefined on input line 449
  Citation `yu2021provably' on page 6 undefined on input line 510
  Citation `yu2021provably' on page 6 undefined on input line 530
  Citation `yu2021provably' on page 6 undefined on input line 546
  Citation `yu2021provably' on page 8 undefined on input line 591
  Citation `zahavy2020apprenticeship' on page 7 undefined on input line 548
  Citation `zahavy2021reward' on page 2 undefined on input line 427
  Citation `zahavy2021reward' on page 2 undefined on input line 430
  Citation `zahavy2021reward' on page 3 undefined on input line 448
  Citation `zahavy2021reward' on page 5 undefined on input line 473
  Citation `zahavy2021reward' on page 5 undefined on input line 485
  Citation `zahavy2021reward' on page 9 undefined on input line 611
  Citation `zhang2020cautious' on page 2 undefined on input line 425
  Citation `zhang2020cautious' on page 3 undefined on input line 448
  Citation `zhang2020variational' on page 2 undefined on input line 425
  Citation `zhang2020variational' on page 2 undefined on input line 427
  Citation `zhang2020variational' on page 2 undefined on input line 430
  Citation `zhang2020variational' on page 3 undefined on input line 448
  Citation `zinkevich2003online' on page 30 undefined on input line 1444
  Reference `LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 419
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 10 undefined on input line 674
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 11 undefined on input line 691
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 11 undefined on input line 719
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 11 undefined on input line 720
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 12 undefined on input line 726
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 13 undefined on input line 744
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 13 undefined on input line 767
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 14 undefined on input line 808
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 15 undefined on input line 857
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 16 undefined on input line 901
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 21 undefined on input line 1063
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 22 undefined on input line 1111
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 22 undefined on input line 1113
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 22 undefined on input line 1121
  Reference `alg:OE' on page 23 undefined on input line 1152
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 10 undefined on input line 674
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 11 undefined on input line 691
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 11 undefined on input line 719
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 12 undefined on input line 723
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 12 undefined on input line 726
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 12 undefined on input line 728
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 12 undefined on input line 736
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 12 undefined on input line 739
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 13 undefined on input line 767
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 16 undefined on input line 899
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 16 undefined on input line 901
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 16 undefined on input line 915
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 17 undefined on input line 923
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 17 undefined on input line 942
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 24 undefined on input line 1219
  Reference `alg:OE_low_rank' on page 35 undefined on input line 1771
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 10 undefined on input line 662
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 10 undefined on input line 681
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 11 undefined on input line 691
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 11 undefined on input line 719
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 12 undefined on input line 728
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 12 undefined on input line 732
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 13 undefined on input line 744
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 13 undefined on input line 753
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 13 undefined on input line 765
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 13 undefined on input line 767
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 14 undefined on input line 777
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 14 undefined on input line 808
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 15 undefined on input line 857
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 16 undefined on input line 899
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 16 undefined on input line 915
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 22 undefined on input line 1113
  Reference `alg:OPDO' on page 23 undefined on input line 1152
  Reference `alg:proj-subgrad' on page 30 undefined on input line 1418
  Reference `alg:proj-subgrad' on page 30 undefined on input line 1437
  Reference `alg:protocol-online-learning' on page 29 undefined on input line 1387
  Reference `appendix-cvx-proof' on page 8 undefined on input line 606
  Reference `appendix-proof' on page 15 undefined on input line 829
  Reference `appendix:proof-lowrank' on page 16 undefined on input line 915
  Reference `appendix:proof-lowrank' on page 17 undefined on input line 926
  Reference `appendix:proof-lowrank' on page 17 undefined on input line 938
  Reference `appendix:proof-lowrank' on page 18 undefined on input line 984
  Reference `ass:black-box' on page 14 undefined on input line 808
  Reference `ass:black-box' on page 17 undefined on input line 955
  Reference `ass:black-box' on page 23 undefined on input line 1152
  Reference `ass:bound-feature' on page 14 undefined on input line 808
  Reference `ass:bound-feature' on page 16 undefined on input line 901
  Reference `ass:bound-feature' on page 17 undefined on input line 942
  Reference `ass:bound-feature' on page 20 undefined on input line 1015
  Reference `ass:bound-feature' on page 22 undefined on input line 1113
  Reference `ass:bound-feature' on page 23 undefined on input line 1152
  Reference `ass:bound-feature' on page 9 undefined on input line 646
  Reference `ass:convex-lipschitz' on page 17 undefined on input line 948
  Reference `ass:convex-lipschitz' on page 20 undefined on input line 1015
  Reference `ass:mle-oracle' on page 16 undefined on input line 901
  Reference `ass:mle-oracle' on page 18 undefined on input line 971
  Reference `ass:realizability' on page 17 undefined on input line 955
  Reference `ass:realizability' on page 18 undefined on input line 971
  Reference `ass:slater' on page 14 undefined on input line 808
  Reference `ass:slater' on page 16 undefined on input line 901
  Reference `ass:slater' on page 23 undefined on input line 1152
  Reference `ass:slater' on page 9 undefined on input line 615
  Reference `ass:slater' on page 9 undefined on input line 618
  Reference `ass:slater' on page 9 undefined on input line 627
  Reference `eq:ball-radius' on page 11 undefined on input line 699
  Reference `eq:ball-radius-low-rank' on page 11 undefined on input line 712
  Reference `eq:ball-radius-low-rank' on page 16 undefined on input line 901
  Reference `eq:bound-difference' on page 28 undefined on input line 1353
  Reference `eq:bound-difference' on page 29 undefined on input line 1381
  Reference `eq:bound-fenchel' on page 20 undefined on input line 1049
  Reference `eq:bound-lag' on page 20 undefined on input line 1049
  Reference `eq:bound-trans-norm' on page 23 undefined on input line 1170
  Reference `eq:boundforall' on page 26 undefined on input line 1278
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 13 undefined on input line 753
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 33 undefined on input line 1565
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 33 undefined on input line 1573
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 8 undefined on input line 586
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 8 undefined on input line 591
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 8 undefined on input line 596
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 8 undefined on input line 598
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 8 undefined on input line 599
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 8 undefined on input line 601
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 8 undefined on input line 603
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 9 undefined on input line 613
  Reference `eq:convex-prob' on page 9 undefined on input line 618
  Reference `eq:define-visit' on page 5 undefined on input line 494
  Reference `eq:dual-optimal' on page 31 undefined on input line 1463
  Reference `eq:dual-prob' on page 31 undefined on input line 1451
  Reference `eq:dual-prob' on page 31 undefined on input line 1455
  Reference `eq:dual-prob' on page 31 undefined on input line 1468
  Reference `eq:dual-prob' on page 31 undefined on input line 1472
  Reference `eq:dual-prob' on page 31 undefined on input line 1483
  Reference `eq:dual-prob' on page 33 undefined on input line 1561
  Reference `eq:lagrangian' on page 9 undefined on input line 642
  Reference `eq:main-bound1' on page 14 undefined on input line 779
  Reference `eq:maxmin-prob' on page 10 undefined on input line 654
  Reference `eq:maxmin-prob' on page 9 undefined on input line 650
  Reference `eq:maxmin-prob' on page 9 undefined on input line 651
  Reference `eq:minimax-prob' on page 10 undefined on input line 657
  Reference `eq:minimax-prob' on page 10 undefined on input line 662
  Reference `eq:minimax-prob' on page 10 undefined on input line 681
  Reference `eq:minimax-prob' on page 9 undefined on input line 646
  Reference `eq:mle' on page 25 undefined on input line 1243
  Reference `eq:perf-metric' on page 6 undefined on input line 510
  Reference `eq:rand-2' on page 23 undefined on input line 1177
  Reference `eq:reg-bound' on page 21 undefined on input line 1057
  Reference `eq:value-norm-bound' on page 23 undefined on input line 1177
  Reference `eq:value-set' on page 14 undefined on input line 777
  Reference `eq:value-set' on page 15 undefined on input line 832
  Reference `eq:value-set' on page 17 undefined on input line 928
  Reference `eq:vio-bound' on page 21 undefined on input line 1060
  Reference `eq:vio-bound-1' on page 32 undefined on input line 1505
  Reference `eq:vio-bound-2' on page 32 undefined on input line 1517
  Reference `lem:appendix-error-lowrank' on page 29 undefined on input line 1381
  Reference `lem:appendix-error-lowrank' on page 29 undefined on input line 1383
  Reference `lem:ball-radius' on page 22 undefined on input line 1104
  Reference `lem:ball-radius' on page 22 undefined on input line 1111
  Reference `lem:bernstein' on page 25 undefined on input line 1230
  Reference `lem:bound-mu' on page 10 undefined on input line 662
  Reference `lem:bound-mu' on page 9 undefined on input line 635
  Reference `lem:couple-lemma' on page 13 undefined on input line 765
  Reference `lem:couple-lemma' on page 20 undefined on input line 1010
  Reference `lem:est-error' on page 15 undefined on input line 867
  Reference `lem:estimate-error' on page 24 undefined on input line 1204
  Reference `lem:log-sum' on page 24 undefined on input line 1202
  Reference `lem:log-sum' on page 29 undefined on input line 1371
  Reference `lem:look_back' on page 28 undefined on input line 1353
  Reference `lem:matrix-sum' on page 29 undefined on input line 1371
  Reference `lem:matrix-sum' on page 36 undefined on input line 1801
  Reference `lem:mle-guarantee' on page 25 undefined on input line 1237
  Reference `lem:potential-ellip' on page 24 undefined on input line 1199
  Reference `lem:potential-ellip' on page 37 undefined on input line 1836
  Reference `lem:self-normalized' on page 22 undefined on input line 1092
  Reference `lem:self-normalized' on page 34 undefined on input line 1737
  Reference `lem:self-normalized' on page 34 undefined on input line 1748
  Reference `lem:shrink-ball' on page 17 undefined on input line 928
  Reference `lem:simulation-lemma1' on page 15 undefined on input line 855
  Reference `lem:simulation-lemma1' on page 23 undefined on input line 1159
  Reference `lem:simulation-lemma1' on page 23 undefined on input line 1164
  Reference `lem:spurious-bound' on page 15 undefined on input line 867
  Reference `lem:spurious-bound' on page 17 undefined on input line 948
  Reference `lem:spurious-bound' on page 29 undefined on input line 1383
  Reference `lem:value-diff-same-r' on page 15 undefined on input line 842
  Reference `lem:value-difference' on page 14 undefined on input line 779
  Reference `lem:value-difference' on page 14 undefined on input line 796
  Reference `lem:value-difference' on page 21 undefined on input line 1057
  Reference `line:mle-est' on page 12 undefined on input line 739
  Reference `line:optimistic-update' on page 11 undefined on input line 691
  Reference `line:optimistic-update' on page 12 undefined on input line 728
  Reference `line:optimistic-update' on page 12 undefined on input line 732
  Reference `line:optimistic-update' on page 13 undefined on input line 767
  Reference `line:optimistic-update' on page 14 undefined on input line 777
  Reference `line:optimistic-update' on page 22 undefined on input line 1120
  Reference `prop:convexity' on page 33 undefined on input line 1563
  Reference `sec:background' on page 17 undefined on input line 950
  Reference `sec:couple-sec' on page 13 undefined on input line 763
  Reference `sec:couple-sec' on page 14 undefined on input line 779
  Reference `sec:couple-sec' on page 15 undefined on input line 865
  Reference `sec:optimization' on page 9 undefined on input line 633
  Reference `thm:beck-theorem' on page 31 undefined on input line 1497
  Reference `thm:beck-theorem' on page 32 undefined on input line 1521
  Reference `thm:bound-up' on page 33 undefined on input line 1551
  Reference `thm:bound-up' on page 33 undefined on input line 1561
  Reference `thm:main-thm' on page 15 undefined on input line 828
  Reference `thm:main-thm' on page 15 undefined on input line 829
  Reference `thm:main-thm' on page 15 undefined on input line 867
  Reference `thm:main-thm' on page 16 undefined on input line 910
  Reference `thm:main-thm' on page 21 undefined on input line 1062
  Reference `thm:main-thm-lowrank' on page 16 undefined on input line 910
  Reference `thm:main-thm-lowrank' on page 16 undefined on input line 914
  Reference `thm:main-thm-lowrank' on page 24 undefined on input line 1207
  Reference `thm:main-thm-lowrank' on page 24 undefined on input line 1208
  Reference `thm:main-thm-lowrank' on page 29 undefined on input line 1383
  Reference `thm:proj-subgrad' on page 20 undefined on input line 1013
  Reference `thm:proj-subgrad' on page 20 undefined on input line 1037
  Reference `thm:vio-bound' on page 14 undefined on input line 779
  Reference `thm:vio-bound' on page 21 undefined on input line 1060
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [refs.bib]
Rule 'bibtex paper': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'paper.aux'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'bibtex paper'
------------
------------
Running 'bibtex  "paper"'
------------
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'paper.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "paper.tex"'
------------
Failure to make 'paper.pdf'
```

There's even an additional error like this in stdout:

```
(.paper.aux
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
 
                   \protect 
l.81 ...rlying Transition Models}{equation.2.9}{}}
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

However there's nothing like the text in the bracket. We only have

```
\subsection{Underlying Transition Models}
```

in the .tex file, so it's weird where the equation.2.9 thing comes from, and I guess it's a consequence of the failed references.  Here's a snippet (the front parts) of my bib file:

```
@inproceedings{abernethy2017frank,
  title={On Frank-Wolfe and Equilibrium Computation.},
  author={Abernethy, Jacob D and Wang, Jun-Kun},
  booktitle={NIPS},
  pages={6584--6593},
  year={2017}
}
@inproceedings{zhou2021provably,
  title={Provably efficient reinforcement learning for discounted mdps with feature mapping},
  author={Zhou, Dongruo and He, Jiafan and Gu, Quanquan},
  booktitle={International Conference on Machine Learning},
  pages={12793--12802},
  year={2021},
  organization={PMLR}
}

@article{dann2017unifying,
  title={Unifying PAC and regret: Uniform PAC bounds for episodic reinforcement learning},
  author={Dann, Christoph and Lattimore, Tor and Brunskill, Emma},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1703.07710},
  year={2017}
}

@inproceedings{2011Improved,
  title={Improved Algorithms for Linear Stochastic Bandits},
  author={ Abbasiyadkori, Y.  and  P'Al, D.  and  Szepesv'Ari, C. },
  booktitle={Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems},
  year={2011},
}

@book{boyd2004convex,
  title={Convex optimization},
  author={Boyd, Stephen and Boyd, Stephen P and Vandenberghe, Lieven},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Cambridge university press}
}
```

And here are the lines containing `Underlying Transition Models` with contexts:

```
\citation{kakade2020information}
\citation{kakade2020information,mania2020active,song2021pcmlp}
\citation{uehara2021pessimistic,agarwal2020flambe,modi2022modelfree}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.3}Examples of the Underlying Transition Models}{7}{subsection.2.3}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{eq:transition}{{8}{7}{}{equation.2.8}{}}
\citation{uehara2022representation}
\citation{yang2019sample,yang2020reinforcement}
\citation{kakade2020information,uehara2022representation}
```

Does anyone have any idea what to do? Any guidance is warmly welcomed!

Comment: Do you need to submit the bbl file since you are providing the bib file?

Comment: The submission instructions don't ask for it. However, I've tried submitting with bbl and without bbl, and neither works :(

Comment: In Overleaf, download the file `paper.aux`, and open it with a text editor.  Post the entirety of all lines that contain `rlying Transition Models`, along with the lines before and after.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post with the context in aux. I use paper.aux in my local directory generated by latexmk (which also works well), since I didn't find aux file in overleaf (they only provide bbl).

Comment: Up next to "Recompile" you can switch the view to "Logs and output files".  Down at the bottom right is a button for "Other logs and files" that should let you download "output.aux".  But reading your post a bit more closely, it appears you would want the aux file JMLR is using.  I'm not sure how you would get that short of asking the volunteer team.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I looked into the tex file line by line and tested it by repeatedly submitting it to the system's compiler, and found that the issue comes from a single equation

```
P_h^*(s) = a * b,
```

after I changed it to `P^{*}_{h}` the compilation's all set. Guess like something's wrong with the system which I do not know... However, it did take me a lot of time to deal with this small issue.

Comment: I believe (but I'm not certain) that the braces are required syntax, even though it works without them in many cases. So the system may not be wrong exactly, if it requires the official syntax. Perhaps the submission instructions could warn people about it.... [I have no idea about the ordering, though.]